# Can I retrieve files from the voice recorder app after they've been deleted?

Tags: htc-thunderbolt, delete

Is there any way I can retrieve files that were accidentally deleted from the voice recorder on an HTC Thunderbolt?

Comment: You deleted them. Android doesn't have a 'trash' that deleted files go to. If it didn't delete the actual file (which would surprise me) you can use a file browser like File Expert (my favorite) to open it.

Answer (score 1):

If the files were stored on a physical microSD card, you may be able to use file recovery software on your computer.  There are a number of undelete and recovery software options, but many cost money. http://pcinspector.de has a flash memory recovery tool for free (Smart Recovery handles flash memory).

Writing more data to the card increases the chance that the file will be overwritten before you recover it.